# Accessing VF picklist value on controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a VF page, which sends mail to a particular set of contacts. My VF and Controller are working fine, and i am able to send mail. However, its the VF UI which is troubling me.

Whenever the dropdown showing the email template (EmailTemplate Object) changes, I need to render a button. But I am not able to access the label of the selected dropdown so that I can work on it. Right now I am using object id in rendered portion of VF which I want to get rid of Here is my VF and Apex:

VF Page:

```xml
<apex:page StandardController="Contact" extensions="SendEmailtoContactController"  showHeader="false" sidebar="false" title="Send Mass Email">    

    <style>    
    #el_loading
    {
       display: none;
    }

    </style>

    <apex:form >
             <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"> </apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Contact" title="Send Mass Email">

            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:selectList value="{!emailTemplate}" size="1" label="Choose Email Template">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!emailTemplateOptions}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!passValueToController}" reRender="btn" />
                    </apex:selectList> 
                </apex:actionRegion>               
                <tr>
                <td>  <apex:inputFile value="{!attBody}" filename="{!attName}"/></td>


                </tr>
                <div align="left" draggable="false" >

                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <div align="center" draggable="false">
                    <apex:outputPanel id="btn">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Send Mass Emails" action="{!sendEmailToContacts}" onclick="onUpload();" rendered="{!(emailTemplate=='00Xq0000001RJoAAAW')}"/> <!-- PROBLEM AREA-->

                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Send Preview Mail" action="{!sendEmailTologgedin}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Close" onClick="window.close();"/>
                    <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                            <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                 </div>
            </apex:form>

    <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb; height:100%;opacity:0.75;width:100%;">
    <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 100px; width: 91px;">
        <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..."  style="width: 40;height:40;"/>
    <span class="waitingDescription">Attachment is Uploading . . . .</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    function onUpload()
    {
        var ul = document.getElementById('el_loading');
        ul.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Relevant pieces of Apex:

```
public with sharing class SendEmailtoContactController{
    public List<SelectOption> emailTemplateOptions {get;set;}
    public String emailTemplate {get;set;}
    public list<EmailTemplate> eTemp = new list<EmailTemplate>();
    public transient blob attBody{get;set;}
    public string attName{get;set;}
    public string commentBody{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    public list<Attachment> attMail;

public SendMassEmailContactController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 

        emailTemplateOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

        emailTemp = new list <EmailTemplate>([Select Id, Name from EmailTemplate where name in ('456test','123test')]);
        for(EmailTemplate et : emailTemp) {
            emailTemplateOptions.add(new SelectOption(et.id,et.name)); 
            eTemp.add(et);
            system.debug('eTemp='+eTemp);

        }
        emailTemplate = emailTemp[0].id;

        contactList = [Select Id, Name,Email,Email_Comments__c,Account.Name from Contact where Newsletter__c = true];
        attMail = new list<Attachment>( [select id, ContentType, Body, parentId From Attachment where parentId in :emailTemp]);
    }

    public void sendEmailToContacts(){
        //-------------------------- Throw error when no attachment present in the email
        if (attname == null || attname ==''){            
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.FATAL,'Select attachment file'));
        }
        else{
            BatchtoSendContactMassEmail bc = new BatchtoSendContactMassEmail();
            Database.executeBatch(bc);
            // Batch simply sends the mail to the contacts
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Map<Id, String>` and populate it with the template Ids and names from your selectOptions,  then create a getter variable that pulls from the map using the selected template ID:

```
public static Map<Id, String> templateMap { get; set; }
public static String selectedTemplate {
  get {
    return templateMap.get(emailTemplate);
  }
}
```